# Array of objects in JavaFX

Tags: java, arrays, javafx

I am supposed to create an array of objects of type `Buttons` but the output it's just one button not multiple as it is supposed to. What Should I do?

```
int numberOfButtons = 20;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfButtons; ++i) {    
    Button[] btn = new Button[numberOfButtons];
    btn[i] = new Button();
    btn[i].setText("Safe!");

    btn[i].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
    });

    FlowPane root = new FlowPane();
    root.getChildren().addAll(btn[i]);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250); 
    primaryStage.setTitle("Button Blast!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: You should probably close your for loop before you create `root`. You should also move `Button[] btn = new Button[numberOfButtons]` before the for loop. Otherwise you're creating every variable within the for loop 20 times.

Comment: Ok, so I did that... But then the method `root.getChildren().add(btn[i]);` doesn't work anymore.

Comment: So add another for loop like: `for(Button b : btn) { root.getChildren().add(b); }`. Or you could probably just do `root.getChildren().addAll(btn)` without the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run in such problems the best thing is to get a paper and a pen and to write down what
 each line of your code does.

your complete code is within the loop. you should narrow it down so that in only contains this:

```
btn[i] = new Button();
btn[i].setText("Safe!");

btn[i].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used JavaFx with Java8 (Stream) in order to solve your issue:

```
    FlowPane fPane = IntStream.range(1, 20)
            .mapToObj(value -> {

                Button button = new Button("Safe!");

                button.setOnAction(event -> {
                    System.out.println("Hello World!");
                });

                return button;

            }).reduce(new FlowPane(), (p, b) -> {

                p.getChildren().add(b);

                return p;
            }, (flowPane, flowPane2) -> flowPane2);

    Scene scene = new Scene(fPane, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Button Blast!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```